# when we should use to "inventory" and "list"

Tags: meaning

Can any one explain those conditions on which we have to use word '**list**' and '**inventory**'

Comment: Have you googled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOAD defines:

> *inventory*: a complete list of item such as property, goods in stock,
>   or the contents of a building 
> [*in our warehouse you'll find a large inventory of new and used bicycles*]

and

> *list*: a number of connected items written or printed consecutively,
>   typically one below the other 
> [*writing a shopping list*]

So, you should use *inventory* and *list* as NOAD says.

Comment: Couldn't OP look up NOAD? Or just google? I don't mean to be rude.